# Adding custom view into NavigationBar not working?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, swift5

I am trying to add custom view to NavigationBar and result not working correct.

```
 public let statusBarHeight: CGFloat = {
    var heightToReturn: CGFloat = 0.0
         for window in UIApplication.shared.windows {
             if let height = window.windowScene?.statusBarManager?.statusBarFrame.height, height > heightToReturn {
                 heightToReturn = height
             }
         }
    return heightToReturn
}()

 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
//        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = true
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
       let barView = UIView(frame: CGRect.zero)
        barView.backgroundColor = .purple
        barView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        if let navBarSize = self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.size {
//            barView.frame.size = CGSize(width: navBarSize.width, height: navBarSize.height + statusBarHeight)
            self.navigationController?.navigationBar.subviews.first?.insertSubview(barView, at: 0)
            NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
                barView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: (self.navigationController?.navigationBar.subviews.first!.leadingAnchor)!),
                barView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: (self.navigationController?.navigationBar.subviews.first!.trailingAnchor)!),
                barView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: navBarSize.height + statusBarHeight )
            ])
        }

        
       
    }
```

See the difference in notch device this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have to make a change in your code, now it's work on all devices even iPhone 12 mini as shown in the image.
[check image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/siEyz.jpg)

```swift
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let barView = UIView(frame: CGRect.zero)
        barView.backgroundColor = .purple
        barView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        if (self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.size) != nil {
            self.navigationController?.navigationBar.subviews.first?.insertSubview(barView, at: 0)
            NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
                barView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: (self.navigationController?.navigationBar.subviews.first!.leadingAnchor)!),
                barView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: (self.navigationController?.navigationBar.subviews.first!.trailingAnchor)!),
                barView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: (self.navigationController?.navigationBar.subviews.first!.topAnchor)!),
                barView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: (self.navigationController?.navigationBar.subviews.first!.bottomAnchor)!),
            ])
        }
    }
```

Comment: my mistake !!!!! i foucsed height of it thank you so much